# Linq query with list of flags

Tags: c#, linq, list, enums, flags

I'm trying to get a list of records from data base using Linq query.

```
public void Main() {
    var filter = new Filter();
    filter.ReceiverState = new List<DocumentState> { DocumentState.Completed };
    var q = from d in Documents
            where filter.ReceiverState.Any(f => (d.ReceiverState & (int)f) != 0)
            select d;
    q.Dump();
}

public class Filter {
    public List<DocumentState> ReceiverState { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum DocumentState {
    Sent = 1,
    NeedClarification = 2,
    Completed = 4,
    NeedResign = 8
}
```

But I get this error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

I have to use a list of flaged enum in the filter. How I can make a right Linq query?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You query has a few smell-ies, 1 you initialize filter and filter.ReceiverState, but yet in your linq you check if filter is null or if filter.ReceiverState contains completed state which will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
var filter = new Filter();
filter.ReceiverStates = new List<DocumentState> { DocumentState.Completed };
var documents = new List<Document>();
var result = documents.Where(d => filter.ReceiverStates.Contains(d.ReceiverState));
```

Comment: this would work, if enum wouldn't have Flags attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a sequence (ReceiverState) to compare it with documents, linq to sql doesn't work this way, what you can do is passing a single value to comapre with, or the other way around get the documents and compare them with your list (ReceiverState)

I'm not sure why you're using a list here, i see you're only looking for documents flagged as completed.

(Haven't try any of this code but i know the approach will work as i used it before)

```
var q = from d in Documents
        where (DocumentState)d.ReceiverState & DocumentState.Completed == DocumentState.Completed
        select d;
```

But if you need to use a list as a filter, you can try this (not best thing to do with big number of records) but it will work, because at the moment you start looping in docs, it's not linq to sql anymore and basically you're comparing a single value at a time.

```
var docs = from d in Documents select d;
foreach(var f in filter.ReceiverState)
{
   docs = docs.Where(x => (DocumentState)x.ReceiverState & f == f)
}
```

Comment: Apart from some missing parentheses this is the correct answer.